# Masonry: Having issues with div layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I am using Masonry to achieve a layout with different widths. Most have the same height, and if not, the idea is that they calculate to line up correctly next to each other.

You can view the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hLangx3g/

And here's my code:

```js
// Javascript
var container = document.querySelector('#masonry-grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.masonry',
  columnWidth: 0
});
```

```css
#masonry-grid {width:80%; margin:0 auto;}
.masonry {background:#069;}
.masonry-3 {width:25%; padding-bottom:25%; background:#0C6}
.masonry-4 {width:33.3%; padding-bottom:33.3%; background:#9C0}
.masonry-6 {width:50%; padding-bottom:50%; background:#C36}
.masonry-8 {width:66.6%; padding-bottom:33.3%; background:#FC9}
.masonry-12 {width:100%; padding-bottom:33.3%; background:#036}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="masonry-grid">
  <div class="masonry masonry-4"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-8"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-3"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-3"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-6"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-3"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-3"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-12"></div>
  <div class="masonry masonry-12"></div>
</div>
```

(The code inserted on Stack Overflow doesn't seem to layout correctly, my jsfiddle is where I'm at so far).

You'll see there are four green (not the lime one) squares of the same width and height. I was hoping that the four boxes would themselves sit in a square, so two on each line, with the big pink box sat to the right of the four. That would then all equal out.

How can I get the four green squares to sit 2x2 with the pink square to the right? I've been racking my brains for hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a non-zero `columnWidth`.  What's happening is that `Masonry` is looking for that variable and being `0`, is using the width of the first element it finds that matches the `itemSelector` (your `masonry-4` object).  You need to set it (setting it to `1` is the best for what you're attempting to do with different widths).

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hLangx3g/1/

Comment: Hi Ford, that's sorted it. Thanks so much for your input, I'm really grateful for it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, this is what you want, right ?

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/4n73om6z/

I added :

HTML : `<div class="column"></div>`

CSS : `.column{width:8.3333333333%;}`

I changed :

JS : `columnWidth: '.column'`

Comment: Hi OxyDesign, sorry I've only just noticed your comment. This also seems to work and makes more sense to me in that one column is 8.333 rec. right?

I'm new to Stackoverflow and both answers answer my question so what do I do? Haha!

Comment: Yes I added a column (1/12, based on the 'grid' thet you set, so 8.33333%) and used it as the reference for masonry like it's recommended in the Masonry doc http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth . And for StackOverflow I think you can only choose one answer. It's up to you

Comment: Thanks OxyDesign, well this also solves my question, thanks very much indeed for helping

Comment: You're welcome. I'm on stackOverFlow for only 5 days so I don't know everything for now but maybe you can vote +1 for my answer even if you chose the other one or mark one of my comment as useful but I'm not sure